# How to transform/migrate indices from self hosted Elasticsearch to a ES docker container?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers, etl

I have a **self hosted** elasticsearch and I wanted to transform all indices to a elasticsearch **docker container**.

What are the possible solutions to move all indices from localhost ES cluster to the ES container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in the internet, I found the answer of my question. It has a simple solution. Just **Copy** -> **Paste**.
The procedure is as follows:

1. **Find the location of indices in the self hosted Elasticsearch**. Go to the elasticsearch directory `/usr/share/elasticsearch/` ( or any other installation directory). In the `conf/elasticsearch.yml` file, find the ***path.data***. (The default is `/var/lib/elasticsearch/`)
2. **Copy** the content of `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/<node id>/indices/`
3. **Paste** those to your ***docker container volume***. `<your-volume-path>/nodes/<node id>/indices/`